# ReactJS set min and max value for number input using final-form-material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-final-form, final-form

I'm using `final-form` and `final-form-material-ui`

I want to set min and max values for number inputs. Already tried

```
InputProps={{ inputProps: { min: 0, max: 10 } }}
```

but it doesn't work.

Also I want to add seconds for `preparation_time` so the format would be 00:00:00.

**codesandbox** https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-brook-g3488?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using the documentation:
https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/examples/field-level-validation

sandbox demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-paper-2dtwf?file=/src/App.js:3139-3391

write your validation in this way:

```
const minValue = (min) => (value) =>
  isNaN(value) || value >= min ? undefined : `Should be greater than ${min}`;

const composeValidators = (...validators) => (value) =>
  validators.reduce((error, validator) => error || validator(value), undefined);
```

then use the validation in this way:

```
 <Field
       name="no_of_slices"
       component={TextField}
       type="number"
       validate={composeValidators(minValue(18))}
       label="Number of slices"
       />
```